# Adding new entry in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I need some help in two problems that I am facing now in my thesis writing.

I want to add a new page with the title "List of Scientific Contribution" at the end of my thesis and its corresponding entry in the TOC.

I am using Easy Thesis template from sharelatex.

In the Thesis.tex file, I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, doublespacing]{Thesis}
\input{Settings/Packages.tex}
\input{Settings/Administrative.tex}
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering

\widowpenalty=500
\clubpenalty=500

\input{Frontpages/Fixed/Title}
\input{Frontpages/DeclarationPage.tex}
\input{Frontpages/Abstract}
\input{Frontpages/Abstrak}
\input{Frontpages/Acknowledgements.tex}
\input{Frontpages/Fixed/TableOfContents.tex}
\input{Frontpages/Fixed/ListOfFigures.tex}
\input{Frontpages/Fixed/ListOfTables.tex}
\input{Frontpages/Abbrev.tex}
\input{Frontpages/Symbols.tex}
%% The Body -------------------------------------------------------
\setstretch{1.3}  % Return the line spacing back to 1.3 the whole document.
\mainmatter       % Begin normal, numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
\pagestyle{fancy}  % Return the page headers back to the "fancy" style

\newpage
%\include{Chapters/Chapter1}    % Introduction
%\include{Chapters/Chapter2}    % Literature Review
%\include{Chapters/Chapter3}    % Research Methodology 
%\include{Chapters/Chapter4}    % Paper 1
%\include{Chapters/Chapter5}    % Paper 2
%\include{Chapters/Chapter6}    % PAper 3
\include{Chapters/Chapter7}     % Conclusion
%\include{Chapters/testChap} 
%\include{Chapters/abbreTest}



%% Bibliography ---------------------------------------------------
\backmatter 
\begingroup
\begin{normalsize}
\bibliographystyle{Files/vjHarvard3}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
    \setlength{\bibsep}{10pt}
    \setstretch{1}
\bibliography{Backmatters/References/all_thesis_chapters} \endgroup


\mainmatter

\begin{appendices}
\input{Backmatters/Appendices/Appendix_A} % Appendix Title
\input{Backmatters/Appendices/Appendix_B} % Appendix Title
\end{appendices}

% List of publication
\input{Backmatters/listofpublication}


\end{document}  % The End
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have placed my new file `\input{Backmatters/listofpublication}` after the appendix section and before the `\end{document}` line.

The file `listofpublication.tex` contain lines as below for testing purpose:

```
\clearpage
\addtotoc{LIST OF SCIENTIFIC CONTRIBUTION}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setstretch{1.3} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}
%############################################################################

\chap{List of Scientific Contribution}


\begin{enumerate}
  \item The first item 

  \item The second item

  \item The third etc \ldots
\end{enumerate}
```

When I complie this, I get the output as below:

[image]

Question.1) In the output, the last line (`2 List of Scientific Contribution`) supposed not to appear in the table of contents. But here I can see it present as the last line. How I can delete this ?

and

Question.2) I want the entries `Apendix` to be in UPPERCASE in TOC.

Appreciate any help with kind.
Thank you.

Comment: instaed of `\chap{List}` use `\chapter*{List}\lhead{List}`, the appendix stuff is not reproducable.

Comment: Please not, that this template cannot be recommended to anybody and the solution posted in the comment above is bad coding, but consistent with the rest of the template. I vote to close as unclear and hope the algorithm zaps the question to not promote the bad coding.

Comment: The interested supporter might want to have a peek: https://de.sharelatex.com/templates/52fdfd8234a287a85245b4c6